# DatePicker New Date type does not match

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using react and typescript, and for datepicker I'm using react-dates.
I want to convert the date to unix when I select it, but I get a ts error.
I get a ts error with a startDate of new Date(startDate).getTime() / 1000.

error

```
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | number | Date'.
  Overload 2 of 4, '(value: string | number): Date', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Moment | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string |
```

number'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.ts(2769)

```
import { DayPickerRangeController } from "react-dates";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import moment from "moment";

import "react-dates/initialize";
import "react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css";

export default function App() {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState<moment.Moment | null>(null);
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState<moment.Moment | null>(null);
  const [focusedInput, setFocusedInput] = useState<"startDate" | "endDate">(
    "startDate"
  );

  console.log(new Date(startDate).getTime() / 1000);

  return (
    <DayPickerRangeController
      startDate={startDate}
      endDate={endDate}
      focusedInput={focusedInput}
      numberOfMonths={2}
      onFocusChange={(focusedInput) => {
        console.log(focusedInput, "focusedInput");
      }}
      onDatesChange={(selectedDates) => {
        if (focusedInput === "startDate") {
          console.log(selectedDates, "startDate");
          setStartDate(selectedDates.startDate);
        } else {
          setEndDate(selectedDates.endDate);
        }
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is correct, as you can’t create a new date from a null value. Instead, make the conversion onDatesChange, so that you know you’ll have a date at that point:

```js
onDatesChange={(selectedDates) => {
        if (focusedInput === "startDate") {
          console.log(selectedDates, "startDate");
          console.log(new Date(selectedDates.startDate).getTime() / 1000);

          setStartDate(selectedDates.startDate);
        } else {
          setEndDate(selectedDates.endDate);
        }
      }}
```

Once you can confirm that’s the shape you want it to be, you can create a function `convertDateToUnix` handling that conversion, so you can reuse it for both start and end dates

Comment: The above code is nothing different from the code I wrote. What has changed?

Comment: You need to see each line as a separate instruction, ran one after the other. Line 9 and 10, you set your startDate and endDate initial value to null. After you do that, you cannot create a `new Date(startDate)` as that will result in `new Date(null)` which is clearly wrong. The difference is that I moved your date creation on the event handler, so that you create the date ONLY once a date has actually been selected, at which point you'll have an actual date rather than a null value.

Comment: I wrote console.log(new Date(selectedDates.startDate).getTime() / 1000); in onDatesChange, but I get the same error.

Comment: Typescript doesn't know when your state is either null or with a date; Wrap it within a condition -> `if (selectedDates.startDate) { .. }`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-cray-pxsny?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: I get an error at the startDate.

Comment: Of course you get the error, as in that sandbox you have added the `Moment` type on `selectedDates`, which is wrong. See https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-mirzakhani-r02rw?file=/src/App.tsx; You'll also note I changed the way dates are converted from moment to Date(), as per standards

Comment: thahk you!!!!!!